# What is the bitmap font which MS Excel uses to replace chosen fonts for small fontsizes?

Tags: excel, windows, fonts, xlsx

I've found that when a cell in Excel (Excel 365 on Windows 10) contains text with font size < 8pt it will be displayed using a bitmap (raster) font instead of whichever font is set for that cell (e.g. Calibri). The same happens when a font of normal size (e.g. 11pt) is displayed smaller due to zooming out of the document.

I need to reproduce Excel's cell width calculation in a C++ program, and for these cases the results are wrong because the font used is different.

[image: Font sizes 6pt & 7pt are the unknown stand-in font, 8pt and 11pt are Calibri as expected.]

On the right are font sizes 8pt and 11pt, displayd as Calibri, on the left is the mystery font at 6pt and 7pt. It is clearly not Calibri, and e.g. Arial at these sizes gets replaces by the same stand-in font.

Does anybody recognize the font? What is its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the "Small Fonts" bitmap font that is included in Windows.